# How to find xpath elements/tags of a specific node

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have a page with the following structure...

```
<doc>
  <tbody>
   .
   .
   .
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>
       .
       .
  </tbody>
  ....
</doc>
```

I'm able to get to the specific table I want with the xpath

```
response.xpath('//tbody')[8].get()
```

but I'm struggling with the syntax to get elements/tags within tbody[8]... so far I've tried

```
>>> response.xpath('//tbody')[8]/tr.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tr' is not defined
```

along with several other attempts but they all fail due to (I believe) syntax. How can I get to tr and td tags inside tbody? No matter what I try I can't seem to add anything after `tbody')[8]` & I can't wrap my head around why...

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're going to need to provide the whole xpath string as an argument to the `xpath()` function, rather than trying to stick pieces of it outside.

The `response.xpath('//tbody')` is returning a list of elements matched by the xpath, and the `[8]` you have there is a *Python* index operator, not part of the xpath. But then you're trying to continue writing an xpath after it, and it's just gibberish to Python.

If you take a look at some of the examples in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html, you should be able to see what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `/tr` supposed to go in the same XPath string:

```
response.xpath('//tbody[9]/tr').get()
```

Also note that despite XPath supports indexing like python, XPath index starts from `1` instead of `0`. So if you could get the correct element using index `[8]` in python, you may want to use index `[9]` in the XPath expression